# How to style drawer (NavigationView) different theme than main activity?

Tags: android, themes, navigation-drawer

I like to use dark theme in my activity, but I would like to have drawer in light theme.

Is it possible to set dark theme for activity AND light for drawer? Drawer should be light, but within dark activity.

Comment: Your question could technically answered "yes it is". But if you would show a little more effort in your question, it is more likely to get a proper response. I'm missing the "what have you tried" part. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added more details into question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this to your navigation view XML

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: I am sorry, I wasnt very precise with asking question - I want to have LIGHT drawer within DARK activity. Is this possible?

Comment: @qkx i have edited my answer. Hopefully this helps you out

Comment: This works!!! You are genius, I tried using android:style, but I didnt think about android:theme :) Thanks man, u saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

To switch between themes dynamically you simply need to call setTheme before super onCreate like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
}
```

Comment: I know hot to switch between themes, that was not the question :)) Maybe I wasnt very precise with asking question - I want to have LIGHT drawer within DARK activity. Is this possible?

Comment: that did not working for me